# How to install apple theme offline on ubuntu?

Tags: 13.10, themes, backup

My friends likes to convert ubuntu theme to apple theme. but due to lack of internet connectivity he can't install apple theme using terminal(through commanding). Is there a way to back up my theme and give him a copy?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can copy .config of your theme in your home directory into USB and copy them to your friend's home directory.